# jQuery - toggle() a form when a button is clicked in a list

Tags: jquery, html, list, selector

Problem: I don't want it to toggle when I am clicking on the table. Only when I click the button(div). Also, there has to be a selector so that other li's tables doesnt toggle.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table.edititem').hide();
    $('.menu-category > li ul li .button').click(function(){
        $('table.edititem', this).toggle();
    });
});
```

I know the problem is: $('table.edititem', >>>this<<<).toggle(); Because the table is not inside the ".button".
We need to grab the parent, but how do we do it?

HTML

```
<ul>
<li>
    Category1
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div>
                <div class="button"></div>
                <table class="edititem">
                </table>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the .parent() function to go up a node, then search for the relevant table.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table.edititem').hide();
    $('.menu-category > li ul li .button').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find("table.edititem").toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your html table(put tr,td). Try this :

**HTML**

```
<ul class="menu-category">
<li>
    Category1
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div>
                <div class="button">dddd</div>
                <table class="edititem"><tr><td>dfdf</td></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table.edititem').hide();
    $('.menu-category > li ul li .button').click(function(){
         console.log($(this).siblings('table.edititem'));
        $(this).siblings('table').toggle(100);
    });
});
```

Here is the working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/JgfMv/